# How to use Spacy NLP from within a website

Tags: python, reactjs, nlp, spacy

I have been practicing with Spacy NLP within the Jupyter Notebook for some time, and have created some scripts that work for what I need.

I also have a website that I have created (built in React). I need to be able to pass data to a Spacy script based on what the user selects on my website, and then need to receive a result again from the Spacy NLP script once it has completed its work on the data passed in.

I have been looking for quite some time (and am new to using Python), and have absolutely no idea how to essentially be able to use / access the Python Spacy scripts from within my website, and also receive information back from the scripts.

Can anyone suggest how to do this? And apologies in advance if this is a stupid question. Many thanks.

Comment: One possible solution would be to setup a lightweight web API using `flask`. Endpoints of that API make the calls to you spacy script. Also have a look at [spacy-services](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-services) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, this depends on what exactly you're trying to do and what you want spaCy to extract. In most cases, you'll want at least an API endpoint that your application can post a string of text to, and that parses the text as a spaCy `Doc`, and returns whatever your application needs. For example, if you need to extract entities, your endpoint would do something like this:

```
def extract_entities(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    entities = [{'start': ent.start_char, 'end': ent.end_char, 'label': ent.label_} 
                for ent in doc.ents]
    return {'entities': entities}
```

Your React app could then do something like this:

```
fetch('http://your-api:8080/extract_entities', { 
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ text })
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({ entities: json.entities }))
```

You'll also want to make sure to preload the model(s) you're using. Especially if you're using spaCy v1.x, the models are quite large and memory intensive – but in any case, you definitely don't want to load the model on each request or session.

Some additional resources:

- To set up your REST API: [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [`hug`](https://github.com/timothycrosley/hug) (my personal favourite – requires Python 3).
- For inspiration: the [`spacy-services`](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-services) repo, which includes REST services for [spaCy's displaCy visualizers](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy) (unfortunately, it's slightly outdated at the moment – but this will be fixed soon!)
- If you need to load and serve different models, and take advantage of caching for better performance, check out the [`spacy_api`](https://github.com/kootenpv/spacy_api) project – a great extension developed by someone from the spaCy community. It helps you load models in a separate, dedicated process. However, if you're new to Python, this might be a bit much to dive into straight away – you're probably better off starting with a very simple approach, and getting to this later on once your app is running.